# In python, can an inner function be interrogated about its parent function?

Tags: python, namespaces

Say we have a function, define in *my_module.py*:

```
def make_function(scalar: float) -> Callable[[float], float]:
    
    def increment(x: float) -> float:
        return x + scalar
    
    return increment
```

And on runtime, I have access to the live inner function objects (and I know that all the relevant code is defined in my_module.py).

```
>> make_function(2)
<function my_module.make_function.<locals>.increment(x: float) -> float>
```

Q: is there an elegant way, from the live object, to obtain information about what its parent function is? In particular I am interested in dynamically generating strings of the format `"my_module.make_function.increment"`. I am looking for a solution which would also work for an arbitrary number of nested levels (i.e. `"my_module.outer_func_1.outer_func_2.inner_func"`).

Note that the answer to my question seems to be (almost) embedded in the `__repr__` of the function object as per my code sample before. But unsure about what internals are behind it and how to access them.

What have I tried?

- inspect module: `inspect.getmodule(func).__name__` but that only returns the module path
- `func.__code__.co_*`, but couldn't find a way to point to the parent function
- playing with `func.__globals__`, but that seemed more complex than needed

Ideally I would like to avoid decorating/modifying the defined functions and only arrive at the answer from inspecting object itself. Any help on how to proceed is much appreciated!

Comment: Why not `f = make_function(2); f.__repr__().replace("<locals>.", "")` ?

Comment: Hi!

Ideally I would have liked to see / understand the code that `__repr__` used, to make sure that the desired behaviour is stable / there are no nasty corner cases which would cause the string to display differently. 

Also, if there is an underlying public method which does the same - have a slight preference to call that directly. However, barring those if that's the best way to access path then yes I will just do what you suggest

Comment: @AzmyRajab I would use `f.__qualname__` for a more "stable" way. `__repr__` probably won't change, but just to be safe...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yeah, I was going to say the same :) `f.__qualname__` is the way to go. Apparently, this property is set at compile time and `<locals>` is always set for inner functions.     https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bcdd3072316181b49d94567bb648825a07ca9ae1/Python/compile.c#L734

Comment: Cool -- I just tried `__qualname__`  for a couple of cases (such as multiple levels of nested) and it does seem to behave consistently / as expected


Thank you both for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the safest bet is just to use `__qualname__`:

```
In [6]: def foo():
   ...:     def bar():
   ...:         def baz():
   ...:             return 42
   ...:         return baz
   ...:     return bar()
   ...:

In [7]: f = foo()

In [8]: f
Out[8]: <function __main__.foo.<locals>.bar.<locals>.baz()>

In [9]:

In [9]: f.__qualname__
Out[9]: 'foo.<locals>.bar.<locals>.baz'
```

So, something like:

```
In [11]: f.__qualname__.replace("<locals>.", "")
Out[11]: 'foo.bar.baz'
```